# What is the term used to remind someone to submit something that is in a rush and important in a business term?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, business-language

as the topic stated, I'm currently in a situation where the term "notification" is kind of over used, so I'm trying to find alternatives to emphasize the importance of the notification.

Here's the scenario - You are supposed to submit three documents at the end of the week, and it is now 2 days before deadline meets.

My first thought was something like a "Submission Reminder", but reminder felt a bit too soft. So I then think of "Overdue notification", however, it's not really overdue yet.

I'd want something that would *let the user feel the sense of urgency and importance*. Is there a better term for it?

Comment: Hello, Willy. Which synonyms for 'notification' and 'reminder' have you discovered, considered (and possibly rejected)?

Comment: "Alert" -- Begin with the word *alert* and the recipient of the message will sit up and take notice: "Alert: Submission due in the next 24 hours! Act now!" (Only if you don't mind giving them a start.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Imminent Deadline
- Important Notice
- Due Date Approaching
- Deadline Approaching